# Is the Númenórean language Adûnaic supposed to be English?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-silmarillion, tolkien-languages

Early Númenóreans spoke Quenya as per learning it from Elves of Beleriand, and then later on in the Second Age Númenóreans created their own language: Adûnaic which differs from Elvish.

Is Adûnaic supposed to be what is later known as Common tongue or was it a different dialect?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I need to establish one thing first:

### The Common Tongue is not English

The Common Tongue is another of Tolkien's [constructed languages](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/115315/31051), more properly called Westron. From Appendix F:

> The language represented in this history by English was the *Westron* or 'Common Speech' of the West-lands of Middle-earth in the Third Age
>
> <sup>*Return of the King* Appendix F I "The Languages and Peoples of the Third Age"</sup>

### Adûnaic is an ancestor of Westron, but they are distinct languages

Again from Appendix F:

> In the years of their power the Númenoreans had maintained many forts and havens upon the western coasts of Middle-earth for the help of their ships; and one of the chief of these was at Pelargir near the Mouths of Anduin. There Adûnaic was spoken, and mingled with many words of the languages of lesser men it became a Common Speech that spread thence along the coasts among all that had dealings with Westernesse.
>
> <sup>*Return of the King* Appendix F I "The Languages and Peoples of the Third Age"</sup>

Comment: I've been confused by these namings before though: Adun is Sindarin, IIRC, for sunset/west. Therefore Adunaic = language of the Westerners/"Westernesseans"/Numenoreans, i.e. Western tongue. And Westron is also "Western tongue". Looking at how Tolkien then represented the language of the Vale people->Rohan with Anglo-Saxon/Old-English, I'd mentally categorised Adunaic vs Westron as Middle-English vs modern English. (to repeat: not equal, but Tolkien "translated" and represented these tongues from the long gone past of Middle-Earth as varietals of English)

Comment: @Marakai Make it Old English rather than Middle and you'll probably have the relationship a bit more accurate: the direct ancestor of the modern common language, but very much distinct.

Comment: @Marakai If you want to be really confused, the actual name of the Westron language is "Adûni." It's worth remembering that both languages originated with the Men of Númenor, hence the similarity in name

Comment: @MattGutting except that Tolkien represented "Rohannic" with Old English, so that slot is/was taken. IIRC, Adunaic itself was derived from "old Mannish" languages, i.e. before Elvish influence. The languages of the Vale peoples was supposed to be closest to that. For that reason I sort of "injected" Adunaic represented as ME. Or a branch similar to what happened in the Northeast of England with the Danish invasions. One could write a whole article on that, but not sure it would be a proper Answer.

Comment: @Marakai Tolkien wanted to make that connection to point out that Hobbitish was a "more evolved" form of the language of the Rohirrim. My point, if you like, is that the Common Tongue is related to Adunaic somewhat as Modern English is to Old English; and in particular not (as you seemed to be suggesting) as Modern English is related to Middle English.

Comment: @MattGutting Would like to see a quote about "evolved". Related yes. Having just read App F again, it's remarkable that along that line he chose Lombardic names for some hobbits, another Germanic language. Being the philologist he was, it's clear that he wanted to portray the complex of "Mannic" language relationships (hobbits were Men after all, in a way) through Germanic languages, including Romance->English influence with Elvish->Mannic. Further prolly needs to go to Chat. :)

Comment: Adunaic (via heavy influence from Khuzdul) had triconsonant roots, which it passed on to Westron. As a result, Adunaic (which is represented as looking rather Semitic) and Westron (represented as a Germanic language) look much different "in translation" that they probably were in-universe.

Answer (score 1):

There is no English language in Tolkien's legendarium (if we don't count the Anglo-Saxon language of Aelfwine character in his earlier versions).

Adunaic became Westron (the Common Tongue), but it was a wholly different language from English.

The Appendices in LotR actually give an example of some Westron words.

Comment: Shouldn't this be a comment about Aelfwine to Jason's answer? I don't see anything else which is different than his answer.